# Weird Category Urls

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, regenerate

I'm having an issue with the way that my URLs are being generated in our Magento 2 store. We are using the Oleg Koval Regenerate Url Rewrites extension and have it running every night to ensure the sites URLs are all friendly.

For the most part, everything is working correctly and the URLs are being generated in the following format: https://new.doublerdistributing.com/marine.html

The issue is that some are being generated with the format: https://new.doublerdistributing.com/catalog/category/view/s/snow/id/6038/

This is weird to me because it does not match the friendly URL format where each parent category makes up each node, and it also does not match the Magento way of /catalog/category/view/id/1234. Instead, it seems to be some merger of the two.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior or maybe knows what's going on here?

Comment: I am experience this issue at the moment have you found what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case for some reason it was because magento did not create URL Rewrite for the category.

so I did: Marketing->Url Rewrites->Add Url Rewrite.

Then in drop down Create URL Rewrite choose: For Category

And add the necessary information. Clear Cache, Reindex and ant the problem should be gone.

Thanks.